# Loading resource bundles from PlugIns folder

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an OS X application in which I want to make some of the string and resources exchangeable. 
I've created a bundle `skin.bundle` and I can easily load resources from it if I put the bundle into the main app bundle (so that it gets put under .app/Contents/Resources) and use this code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"skin" ofType:@"bundle"];
if (path != nil) {
   self.skinBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
   [self.skinBundle load];
}
```

The [Cocoa bundle documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/Componentizing.html) talks up using the PlugIns (.app/Contents/PlugIns I believe?) folder for modular applications so I tried to do that, by changing the above slightly.

```
NSString *plugins = [[NSBundle mainBundle] builtInPlugInsPath];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"skin" ofType:@"bundle" inDirectory:plugins];
```

But now `path` is nil. I've also tried `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"skin" ofType:@"bundle" inDirectory:@"PlugIns"]` with identical results.

The bundle contains a valid Info.plist file (for code signing purposes).

I can live with the first approach but of course I've gotten curious. Come to think of it, it might be better to look for the skin.bundle in the Application Support folder so it easily survives upgrades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that NSBundle can only see resources within itself so asking for `[NSBundle mainBundle]` only lets you load from Contents/Resources. Obvious when you know it.

This works well for loading from the global Application Support directory (note that in this particular case, I'm loading from a shared AppSupport directory for our software suite, so `kApplicationSupportDirectory` is a hard-coded constant)

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSLocalDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appSupDir = [paths firstObject];
appSupDir = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kApplicationSupportDirectory];
NSString *path = [appSupDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"skin.bundle" ];
id skinBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
```

I've also stopped loading the bundle - it was a resource bundle without a principal class so it cannot/need not be loaded.